# Creating a Heatmap using ggmap with the color scale being based on a numeric variable (not count of observation)

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap, contour, ggmap

I am using `ggmap` to plot a heatmap of length of NYC taxi trip durations. I would like to use the trip duration as my color scale. I have a large amount of observations that have a pickup lat/long that I am able to plot easily on a map of NYC. Trip duration is in seconds and is available for each observation.

However, I am trying to figure out the best way to utilize something like `stat_density2d` to plot contours around certain areas that have higher trip duration (maybe could use an average in a certain area?). I am also grouping my plots by month.

How can I accomplish this? My below code plots this but I believe my scale is in terms of # observations and not the numeric trip_duration variable.

```
library(ggmap)
nyc_map <- get_map(location = c(lon = median(nyc_train2$pickup_longitude), lat = median(nyc_train2$pickup_latitude)), maptype = "terrain", zoom = 13)

pickup_trip_duration_plot <- ggmap(nyc_map) + 
                  geom_density2d(data = nyc_train2, aes(x = pickup_longitude, y = pickup_latitude, fill = trip_duration), size = 0.3) + 
                  stat_density2d(data = nyc_train2, aes(x = pickup_longitude, y = pickup_latitude, fill = ..level.., alpha = ..level..), size = 0.01, bins = 16, geom = "polygon") + 
                  facet_wrap(~ pickup_month_name, ncol = 3) +
                  scale_fill_gradient(low = "yellow", high = "red") + 
                  ggtitle("Trip Duration Heatmap by Month for Pickup Locations") +
                  scale_alpha(range = c(0, 0.3), guide = FALSE)
pickup_trip_duration_plot

# I believe this may have something to do with why I am having plotting issues
# with a numeric value?
Warning message:
Ignoring unknown aesthetics: fill
```

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the `weights` aesthetic in `geom_density_2d()`. I think that might do the trick.